# Get available reactions of message in telethon

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, telethon

In windows version of Telegram you see the list of available reactions (which you can submit on the message) in right of message. How can i get that list using `telethon`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to fetch the chat's full info that has target message.

```py
full_chat = await client(
    telethon.functions.channels.GetFullChannelRequest(
        channel
    )
)
print(full_chat.full_chat.available_reactions)
```

Comment: i thought this is a property of message while i should search for that in channel's property.